# Ckeditor cannot save textarea value using ajaxForm

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try save using ajaxForm :

```
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#form').ajaxForm( {
    target: '#preview', 
        success: function() { 
        } 
    }); 

});
</script>

<form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="save.php">

    <textarea name="content" id="content" class="ckeditor editor" style="width:400px; height:100px;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>

</form>
```

The problem is when im using ckeditor the textarea value cannot save into db, did i miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's ckeditor?

Init ckeditor like this

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content');
```

If you still can't submit data by ajaxForm, try to get data from ckeditor and submit by general ajax

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData();
$.post('url'
, { data : data }
, function(data) {
    //do something
});
```